# Number of orbits of the action of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

What are the number of orbits  of the action of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by left multiplication?

The question is quite difficult to comprehend, as I am unable to use the burnside lemma, which is used for finite groups(i think). Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider any two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. Is there always a matrix in $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb R)$ that transforms one into the other? Or are there exceptions where this is not possible?

Comment: Since the matrices are invertible, therefore, any vector could be transformed any other vector, as every linear equation would have a unique solution. Thus, the orbit would be one. Is it right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: No. I mentioned possible exceptions for a reason :-) Which vector can you not produce with an invertible matrix?

Comment: I think there must be two orbits- one consisting of the zero vector, and the other- non-zero vectors. Am I right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: Exactly.

Comment: the other is the **set of** nonzero vectors.